# C# - Get class field property value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a Class which consists of other classes which have properties like this:

```
public class classA {
    public classAA classAA = new classAA();
    public classAB classAB = new classAB();

}

public class classAA {
    public string propertyA { get; set; }        
}

public class classAB {
    public string propertyB { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to iterate over all classA fields, then iterate over their properties and get their values.
I have created simple console application to test this.

```
classA classA = new classA();
classA.classAA.propertyA = "A";
classA.classAB.propertyB = "B";

    foreach (FieldInfo memberAField in classA.GetType().GetFields()) {
        Console.WriteLine(memberAField.Name + " " + memberAField.MemberType + " " + memberAField.FieldType);
        foreach (PropertyInfo classAProperty in memberAField.FieldType.GetProperties()) {
            Console.WriteLine("name: " + classAProperty.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(" to value: " + classAProperty.GetValue(memberAField));
            }
        }
```

Now I don't know what to pass to GetValue function. I have tried everything I could think of, but I always get error "Object does not match target type."
I think the problem is that memberAField is FieldInfo object, but how can I get the actual System object?

EDIT: Thank you both for answers! Also, I do not think that this should be marked as a duplicate as I see this as different problem. Titles are similiar, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass the instance from which you want to [get the value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx).

First you have to get `memberAField.GetValue(classA)` so you have the value of the field, equivalent to `classA.classAA`. Then call get value using this result `classAProperty.GetValue(memberAField.GetValue(classA))`, equivalent to `classA.classAA.PeropertyA`.

```
        Console.WriteLine(" to value: " + classAProperty.GetValue(memberAField.GetValue(classA)));
```

Full code :

```
classA classA = new classA();
classA.classAA.propertyA = "A";
classA.classAB.propertyB = "B";

foreach (FieldInfo memberAField in classA.GetType().GetFields()) {
    Console.WriteLine(memberAField.Name + " " + memberAField.MemberType + " " + memberAField.FieldType);
    object memberAValue = memberAField.GetValue(classA);
    foreach (PropertyInfo classAProperty in memberAField.FieldType.GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + classAProperty.Name);
        if (memberAValue == null)
            Console.WriteLine(" no value available");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(" to value: " + classAProperty.GetValue(memberAValue));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`GetValue` requires an object instance for which you are getting the property value, so you just need to call `FieldInfo.GetValue` on the initial object:

```
foreach (FieldInfo memberAField in classA.GetType().GetFields()) {
    Console.WriteLine(memberAField.Name + " " + memberAField.MemberType + " " + memberAField.FieldType);

    object memberAValue = memberAField.GetValue(classA);  // instance to call GetValue on later.

    foreach (PropertyInfo classAProperty in memberAField.FieldType.GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + classAProperty.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(" to value: " + classAProperty.GetValue(memberAValue));
        }
    }
```